# How to convert the yaml to csv with array?

Tags: yaml, jq, yq

The example:

```
ProductLine:
  ProductLineName: aa
  ADO_FeedsList:
    - organizationName: bb
      Project:
        - ProjectName: cc
          ProjectFeedsName: 
          - dd
          - ee
        - ProjectName: ff
          ProjectFeedsName:
          - gg
          - hh
  OtherInfo: N/A
```

I expected the following output:

```
bb,cc,dd
bb,cc,ee
bb,ff,gg
bb,ff,hh
```

I have tried :

```
yq -o csv '.ProductLine.ADO_FeedsList[] |[.organizationName] + (.Project[]|.ProjectName)' test.yaml
```

It can output:

```
bb,cc
bb,ff
```

Then i tried:

```
yq -o csv '.ProductLine.ADO_FeedsList[] |[.organizationName] + (.Project[]|.ProjectName) + (.Project[]|.ProjectFeedsName[]|[.])' test.yaml
```

Error: !!seq (ProductLine.ADO_FeedsList.0.Project.0.ProjectFeedsName.0) cannot be added to a !!str (ProductLine.ADO_FeedsList.0.Project.0.ProjectName)

How to write the ProjectFeedsName array command?

I am a yq new user,could you share the method to format this yaml ?
Or is there any other way to format this yaml to csv?

Answer (score 2):

When adding arrays, make sure that all parts have brackets:

```bash
yq -o csv '
  .ProductLine.ADO_FeedsList[] | [.organizationName] + (
    .Project[] | [.ProjectName] + (.ProjectFeedsName[] | [.])
  )
' test.yaml
```

```
bb,cc,dd
bb,cc,ee
bb,ff,gg
bb,ff,hh
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use gojq, the Go implementation of jq; if you don't mind the way `@csv` quotes fields, you could consider:

```
gojq -r --yaml-input '
.ProductLine.ADO_FeedsList[]
| [.organizationName] + 
  ( .Project[] | [.ProjectName] + (.ProjectFeedsName[]|[.]) )
| @csv
```

If you do mind, then perhaps replacing `@csv` by `| join(",")` will suffice.